# How to set the column name for first column in python pandas? Weird error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have an xls with the title row as :

```
             AZ-Phoenix     CA-Los Angeles CA-San Diego
YEAR         PHXR           LXXR           SDXR
January 1987  59.33         54.67          77
February 1987 59.65         54.89          78
March 1987    59.99         55.16          79
```

Note : the first row has no name above "YEAR column". How to set the name as YEAR for this row?

```
   I have tried : data_xls = data_xls.rename(columns={data_xls.columns[0]: 'YEAR'})
```

But it is replacing the AZ-Phoenix row with YEAR. and i cant really change the column i want to .

How to change this row??

Comment: The first column is an index. You can try `data_xls = data_xls.reset_index()` to make it a column.

Comment: I tried reset.index. It is adding a index collumn

Comment: To be clear, is what you pasted the output after you imported or the format of the Excel file?

Comment: Yea this was imported from the excel file

Answer (score 6):

YEAR is not a column, it's an index here.
try:

```
df.index.name = 'foobar'
```

or:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

in this case, YEAR will become a normal column and you can rename it.

Answer (score 1):

If the text you pasted was the format of the Excel file which looked like this:

[image: excel screenshot]

you can handle this in a couple of ways:

You can pretend that the two lines are multilevel indexes:

```
df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=[0,1])
```

This results in a DataFrame which you can index like this:

```
df['AZ-Phoenix']
```

resulting in

```
YEAR         PHXR
1987-01-01  59.33
1987-02-01  59.65
1987-03-01  59.99
```

If the first row is actually superfluous (it seems like the airport is already uniquely defined by the the three letter airport code in there with an R tacked on), you can simply ignore that row when importing and get a "flatter" DataFrame:

```
df_flat = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx', skiprows=1, index_col=0)
```

This gives you something you can index by the airport code:

```
df_flat.PHXR
```

gives

```
YEAR
1987-01-01    59.33
1987-02-01    59.65
1987-03-01    59.99
Name: PHXR, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

By using  `rename_axis`

```
df.rename_axis('YEAR',1).rename_axis('YEAR',0) # change YEAR to whatever you need for rename :) 
Out[754]: 
YEAR  value           timestamp
YEAR                           
0      1    2017-10-03 14:33:52
1     Water 2017-10-04 14:33:48
2      1    2017-10-04 14:33:45
3      1    2017-10-05 14:33:30
4     Water 2017-10-03 14:33:40
5     Water 2017-10-05 14:32:13
6     Water 2017-10-04 14:32:01
7      1    2017-10-03 14:31:55
```